# Weird glitch on card hover

Tags: html, css, sass

my problem is I used some effect to make the card float using transform(translate) and some shadow and it works just fine, but whenever I come near the edges which is the end of the card width/height, it starts to glitch out with the animation, I believe I know why this is happening but I'm not quite sure how to fix it.. thanks!

[image: gif showing the problem when hovering a card]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wanted to mentioned that the solution to that kind problems is wrapping the floating item with a wrapper and put the hover action on that wrapper not on the component itself.

so for example:

```
.card:hover{
    box-shadow: -10px 0 10px 0;
    transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}
```

Should turn into this:

```
.card-wrapper:hover .card{
    box-shadow: -10px 0 10px 0;
    transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}
```